# Degrading jQuery, HTML5 heavy site

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I'm putting together a website that is using a [jQuery nav-scroll plugin](http://f6design.com/journal/2011/08/06/build-a-parallax-scrolling-website-interface-with-jquery-and-css/comment-page-1/#comment-164627);  it's a great resource, and is functional in IE, however it was developed using a lot of HTML 5 tags, which I ended up creating styles for and perfecting the correlating CSS with.

Now, obviously, the site looks like a disaster in IE 6 & 7 as all the styles set to work with the HTML5 tags are not being rendered. Is my only option an conditional IE style sheet? Is there a better way?

The biggest problem is the styles are not being rendered in older IE versions and everything is being pushed, largely, to the right because of it. I'm also calling for a ['sticky jQuery' slide out menu/box](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/13/end-of-page-slide-out-box/comment-page-1/#comment-168040) twice - one at the top of site, one at the bottom of view. Again styles ignored, allowing functionality, but rendering terrible (uses CSS3 drop-shadows).

What would you guys suggest, conditional IE style-sheet the only way?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers on your questions, or you're unlikely to get answers in the future.

Comment: I'm the author of the jQuery demo (it's not a plugin) you mention in your question. In my demo I used Modernizr and Eric Myer's CSS reset. So Dan Short's answer is right on the money.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to get older browsers (especially IE) to render the HTML5 tags. [Read more about it here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#modernizr).

To pull in dosboy's suggestion, he's correct. [According to the Modernizr docs](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#howitworks), you should probably set them to `display: block` as well as using the Modernizr script itself. You could also tie in the [HTML5 Reset stylesheets](http://html5reset.org/) for the ultimate in HTML5 goodness.

Comment: Additionally, make sure you set the new HTML5 elements to `display:block;`. See http://grinninggecko.com/displaying-html5-elements-correctly-with-modernizr/ for more details.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys. I'm definitely going to check into 'Modernizr' - what do you think of the approach of; embedding Divs within the HTML 5 articles for IE and/or calling them with a 'conditional style'? Bad approach?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't go that route, as it basically goes against the whole point of HTML5, which is semantic markup. Modernizr can do everything you need it to do to make those elements available and style-able in IE. So need to clutter your markup with more `div`s just for IE's sake.